# JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data <Var Xml>

Tags: json

I have a problem with this code

```
var Xml = '<test>test</test>';
    var Parameter = '&Xmldatabase=' + Xml;
    var ReturnDatabase = JSON.parse(invokeWS("Test.asmx", 
    "GetDataTest", Parameter)).Table;
```

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
can you guys help me

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: i'm sorry about this, i will read the link you give to me  @JeroenHeier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.parse is giving you an error because the input you have supplied (that is, the result of the function `invokeWS()`) is not valid JSON. Since you have given us no clue what the function invokeWS() does, we have no way of telling you why it returns invalid JSON.